# Ms-access "Great Than" or equal query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have an Ms-access DB that contain 40 students and I want to find students who are at least 18 years old.

I tried to use this code but it doesn't work!

```
Try
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DBConnect().selectdata(String.Format("SELECT ID, Name FROM Students where Age > %{0}%", FlatTextBox8.Text))
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt.Rows(i)(0), dt.Rows(i)(1))
    Next
    dt.Dispose()
    dt = Nothing
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you have an empty Try-Catch?  If you are getting an exception, you won't see it.  What happens when you debug it?

Comment: You have some kind of custom "selectdata" thing happening that we can't see how it works.  You should always use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Why do you have percent signs around your data?

Answer (score 0):

Name is a reserved word, so try with:

```
String.Format("SELECT ID, [Name] FROM Students where Age > {0}", FlatTextBox8.Text))
```

That said, use parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use parametrized query in order to avoid sql injection.

This little function will fill and return a `DataTable` with the value you are looking at!

```
Private Function GetData() As System.Data.DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim sqlCmd As String = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Students where Age > @Age"
    Using myConnection As New SqlConnection(your_connection_string)
        myConnection.Open()
        Using myDataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd, myConnection)
            myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.Int) 'Change the type if your DB Table has another type
            myDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters("@Age").Value = Convert.ToInt16(FlatTextBox8.Text) 'Change the type if your DB Table has another type
            myDataAdapter.Fill(dt)
        End Using
        myConnection.Close()
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function
```

Now it's time to call it inside your code:

```
Try
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    Dim dt As DataTable = GetData()
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(i + 1, dt.Rows(i)(0), dt.Rows(i)(1))
    Next
    dt.Dispose()
    dt = Nothing
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Err.Clear
End Try
```

As you can notice, I also added a `MsgBox()` that will show you the error message if an exception is thrown. I found this very helpful while debugging.